# While loop with .hasNext condition running infinitely

Tags: java

I know this has been asked many times on StackOverflow, but i've tried many different solutions, and none of them have worked. So i've decided to ask the community on what to do. Here is the relevant snippet from my code.

```
public class Calculator
{
  public static void main(String[]args)
  {
     ArrayList<String> inputStorage = new ArrayList<String>();
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     String rawInput;
     boolean mainLoop = true;

     String exitInput;
     String mainMenuInput;

     while(mainLoop == true)
     {
        mainMenuInput = input.nextLine()
        switch(mainMenuInput)
        {
           case "Expression":
               System.out.println("Type an expression");
               while(input.hasNext)
               {
                  rawInput = input.next();
                  inputStorage.add(rawInput);
               }
               break;

           case "Equation":
               System.out.println("Type an equation");
               while(input.hasNext)
               {
                  rawInput = input.next();
                  inputStorage.add(rawInput);
               }
               break;
          case "exit":
              System.out.println("Are you sure you want to exit")
              exitInput = input.nextLine();
              switch(exitInput)
              {
                 case "yes":
                 case "Yes":
                 mainLoop = false;

                 case "no":
                 case "No":
                 break;

                 default:
                 System.out.println("That was not an option")
                 break;
              }
          default:
                 System.out.println("That was not an option");
                 break;

        }
     }
```

Keep note, this is just the part of my code that takes in input from the console with nothing else included. I have other things setup that require the code to be in this format.

Here is a list of what i've tried and hasn't worked:

- replace input.hasNext() with input.hasNextLine()
- replace input.hasNext() with input.next() != null
- making exit condition if input.next = null
- making exit condition if input.next() = "\n"
- making exit condition if input.next() = "\r"

Here is a list of things that won't work for the rest of my code:

- BufferedReader (and all methods and aspects of it)
- replace input.next() with input.nextLine()

With that said, i have seen a way of doing this by making an exit condition based on the ASKII value of the character newLine. The only problem is that I have found no good way of implementing ASKII values of characters into java code (or at least none that would work with my code), and in order to implement it, I would need to know how the Scanner class uses the Next Line character. But this is just one proposed solution, and i'm sure someone has a better way of ending an input loop like this when enter is pressed.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `Scanner` is handling *opened* stream (`System.in`) it can't be sure that this stream is not in the middle of creating and sending more data, which means it can't return false until

- such stream will be closed
- we will receive data representing end of stream.

Because of that

```
while(input.hasNext()){
    ...
}
```

is bad idea because you are blocked by `hasNext()` until you get proper data (or strim will be closed).

Proper solution depends on your scenario. If you know how many numbers you want to read simply use

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
    ...
    rawInput = input.next();
    ...
}
```

In scenario in which you want to handle tokens from only one line you could first read that line and then tokenize it with separate Scanner

```
Scanner lineScanner  = new Scanner(input.nextLine());
while(lineScanner.hasNext()){
    rawInput = lineScanner.next();
    inputStorage.add(rawInput);
}
```

Comment: No. I did think of that, but I don't know how many numbers i'm going to read ahead of time. Plus, the input storage will need to hold any input, not just numbers. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: You need to somehow know where is the end of data you want to read. Usually it is either predefined amount (even based on earlier user input) or some special character (some stop word like "exit" or `-1` value) or even line separator - in last case you would need to use `nextLine` instead of `next` in main scanner because `next` sees line separators as whitespace which is tread as delimiter between tokens.

Comment: I was thinking of having the user end every input with a ";", but there would be no way to tell if they hadn't. As for the readline function, I need to be able to differentiate between tokens and process each one as a number, command(+, -, *, x, /, ^, =), or a variable(math kind, not java) I also need to process them according to what tokens come before, and after. Unless you know of a way to split the string created by the readline function into its tokens, I can't use that.

Comment: "*Unless you know of a way to split the string created by the readline function into its tokens*" my last update show you how to do it. Simply use another Scanner which will handle line you read. You can also use `line.split("\\s+")` to split on one or more continues whitespaces.

Comment: This works(line scanner) ! Thank you for finally concluding my three day search.

Comment: @JavaNoob You are welcome :) and congrats on having will to spend three days on searching. That is not something you see often.

Answer (score 8):

You never set mainLoop to false at the end. You don't really need nested while loops too, only the one containing `hasNext`

Comment: I said that this was just the relevant snippet of my code needed to ask the question.  mainLoop his the loop surrounding the entire program because I have a main menu set up in it. The code I provided you with is in a case in a switch statement in the main menu. mainLoop has its own exit conditions applied to it accessed from the main menu i have setup (not included in this code)

Comment: Well based on the snippet, mainLoop is causing the infinite loop. Could you please post more of your code?

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to StackOverflow, but I just did.

Comment: Thanks. We'll have a look.

Comment: Try using hasNextLine instead of just hasNext

Answer (score 0):

you can try this if it should work using read line :

```
BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String line;
while((line=stdIn.readLine()) !=null && line.length()!=0){

}
```