# Scanner stop when there's no more lines to read

Tags: java

I'm trying to read from `System.in`.
The Input is in this type :
The first number is the number of test cases, then in integer then some lines.

```
2

10
c 1 5
c 2 7
q 7 1

1
q 1 1
c 1 1
q 1 1
```

The problem is that while loop doesn't exit when i finish the last test despite that there's `sc.hasNext()` condition in the loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int testCases = sc.nextInt();

    for(int i=0;i<testCases; i++){
        int numberOfQuestions = 0;
        int numberOfSuccessufulQuestions = 0;
        int computerNumber = sc.nextInt();
        Graph g = new Graph();

        while(!sc.hasNextInt() && sc.hasNext()){
            String type = sc.next();
            if (type.trim().equals("\n"))
                break;
            if(type.equals("c")){
                int a = sc.nextInt();
                int b = sc.nextInt();
                g.setEdge(a, b);
            }else if(type.equals("q")){
                visited = new HashMap<>();
                int a = sc.nextInt();
                int b = sc.nextInt();
                numberOfQuestions++;
                if(a == b){
                    numberOfSuccessufulQuestions++;
                }
                else if(g.isNodeExist(a) && g.isNodeExist(b)){
                    if(connected(g, a, b)){
                        numberOfSuccessufulQuestions++;
                    }
                }   
            }  
        }

        System.out.println(numberOfSuccessufulQuestions+ ","+ (numberOfQuestions - numberOfSuccessufulQuestions) );
    }
}
```

Comment: Graph is abstract cant be instantiated.

Comment: `if (type.trim().equals("\n")) break;` should use `continue;` instead. Otherwise the test case ends after the first line.

Comment: 'hasNext()' won't be false unless you end the stream. There aleady equal question about stopping scanner on 'System.in'.

Comment: [While loop with .hasNext condition running infinitely](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36094804/1393766)

Comment: Is there any other method which is more suitable for input that i have rather than scanner ?

Comment: Why not terminate the loop yourself if you have the desired inputs?

Comment: Scanner should be fine here. You probably could simply read data fixed number of lines (based on first value). Later you could use another scanner to handle content of each line if you want to use `nextInt` method. You could also consider reading content from file. This way scanner will know when to end (since files have max size/length).

Comment: @Thihara I don't know the number of lines, i just know the number of test cases, each test case has many lines like `10
c 1 5
c 2 7
q 7 1` @Pshemo Yes when i read from a file it works fine,i will try to une another scanner for every line.

Comment: Is number of lines in each test case always 3 (I am counting line which start with alphabetic character)?

Comment: @Pshemo No, it's not always three, that's why i'm trying to use while loop on those lines.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner is fine since it looks like you want to input adhoc information.

The problem is that sc.next() doesn't get triggered by a simply pressing enter in the console.

The solution I see here to terminate the loop with a command.

Instead of `if (type.trim().equals("\n"))` use  something like `(type.trim().equals("exit"))`

Comment: I can't change the input format, i have to extract data from it without changing the input.

Comment: In which case you are better off using a file.